# Arithmetic Progression in Python without storing all the values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to represent an array of evenly spaced floats, an arithmetic progression, starting at a0 and with elements a0, a0 + a1, a0 + 2a1, a0 + 3a1, ...
This is what numpy's arange() method does, but it seems to allocate memory for the whole array object and I'd like to do it using an iterator class which just stores a0, a1 and n (the total number of elements, which might be large).
Does anything that does this already exist in the standard Python packages?
I couldn't find it so, ploughed ahead with:

```
class mylist():
    def __init__(self, n, a0, a1):
        self._n = n
        self._a0 = a0
        self._a1 = a1

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i < 0 or i >= self._n:
            raise IndexError
        return self._a0 + i * self._a1

    def __iter__(self):
        self._i = 0
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self._i >= self._n:
            raise StopIteration
        value = self.__getitem__(self._i)
        self._i += 1
        return value
```

Is this a sensible approach or am I revinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one thing that you are doing wrong is that it should be `for i, x in enumerate(a): print i, x`.

Also, I'd probably use a generator method instead of the hassle with the `__iter__` and `next()` methods, especially because your solution wouldn't allow you to iterate over the same `mylist` twice at the same time with two different iterators (as `self._i` is local to the class).

This is probably a better solution which gives you random access as well as an efficient iterator. The support for the `in` and `len` operators are thrown in as a bonus :)

```
class mylist(object):
    def __init__(self, n, a0, a1, eps=1e-8):
        self._n = n
        self._a0 = a0
        self._a1 = a1
        self._eps = eps

    def __contains__(self, x):
        y = float(x - self._a0) / self._a1
        return 0 <= int(y) < self._n and abs(y - int(y)) < self._eps

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if 0 <= i < self._n:
            return self._a0 + i * self._a1
        raise IndexError

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self._a0
        for i in xrange(self._n):
             yield current
             current += self._a1

    def __len__(self):
        return self._n
```

Comment: your membership test is broken due to floating point arithmetic. Try something like: `return abs(y - int(y)) < .0001 and 0 <= int(y) < self._n` the magic number `.0001` should probably be smaller and configurable.

Comment: there's still a possibility that `y` will compare as greater than `self._n` due to floating point issues when it really shouldn't. Similarly for less than zero. You can dodge that by converting it to an `int`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can see a potential problem with __iter__ though if a0 is large and a1 very small... if I repeatedly add a very small quantity to a large one won't I get bitten by round-off sooner or later?

Comment: @user293594: probably yes. If you expect such use-cases, it's better to use multiplication in `__iter__` as you did in your original `__getitem__` method.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers answer the immediate problem.  Note that if all you want is an iterator and you don't need random access, there's no need to write a whole iterator class.

```
def mylist(n, a0, a1):
    for i in xrange(n):
        yield a0 + i*a1
```

Comment: There's no need to write anything...`itertools.count()` already exists.

Comment: @Tim: If you happen to be in 2.7, though the real point was showing the use of `yield` which the OP may not be aware of--it's really not too often that you actually need to write an iterator class manually.

Comment: You're right, although `itertools.count()` has been there since 2.3; before 2.7 you do need to implement the `step` parameter manually.

Comment: I think we can infer from the presence of `__getitem__` that OP _does_ want random access.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: Not at all.  Extranneous methods are often added because they seem like a good idea for "completeness", not because they're actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Only for reasons that are probably obvious to someone out there, iterating over mylist: for i,x in enumerate(a): print i,a doesn't return the values I expect but just a whole lot of references to the mylist instance. What am I doing wrong?

The culprit is `print i,a`. You are printing `a`, which is an array. You ought to print `x` instead. Chane this line to:

```
print i,x
```

Also a couple of things:

1. Change you class name to TitleCase. For e.g. `class MyList` or `class Mylist`.
2. It is a good idea to inherit from `object` if you are using Python 2.x. So `class MyList(object): ...`

Answer (score 0):

You're enumerating over `a`, so printing it will print a lot of references to it. Print `x` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a [built-in generator](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) for this (Python 2.7 and up):

```
import itertools
mygen = itertools.count(a0,a1)
```

If you don't have Python 2.7 yet (Python 2.4 and up):

```
import itertools
mygen = (a0 + a1*i for i in itertools.count())
```

Comment: if you look at the class though, OP does seem to want random access

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: You're right. I was thrown off by "I'd like to do it using an iterator class"...